Reaching the bound of Boneh and Durfee Attack
According to the paper, theoretically,we can get $\delta=0.292 \lt 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$,but how to set the lattice and implement it in sagemath? I generated some data
by
In [1]: from Crypto.Util.number import *

In [2]: p,q = getPrime(512),getPrime(512)

In [3]: n = p*q

In [4]: phi = (p-1)*(q-1)

In [5]: delta = .292

In [6]: 1024*0.292
Out[6]: 299.008

In [7]: d = getPrime(299)

In [8]: d.bit_length()
Out[8]: 299

In [9]: e = inverse(d,phi)

In [10]: n
Out[10]: 77152450324579978605705878380953489025137467999365676770835669295610070596697998387621044414831607410403535004632412022296296976529985483589666309339275957408065071053526712481587105439739754343760825521301008964684098748502393081452839247836412481318112835367928801391057188195596017427632133363816349402431
In [11]: e
Out[11]: 22562243260316030756538486226064418344582843528762347551355824866271446618260642669465138088338756106648939445307770299906404157692054046711764078043845269918926959977078451991173612264438949546823639240359263313121471952904933006714484654882106402549732967952329699595769849123469165125767214839493143633967

I referred to this repo https://github.com/mimoo/RSA-and-LLL-attacks/blob/master/boneh_durfee.sage
but how to use sagemath to recover d from known n,e with delta = .292?
